# Сортировка линейных списков

Tags: pascal, сортировка

Не могу написать сортировку односвязного списка вставками. Вроде бы что-то нашел, и оно даже работает, но там все непонятно. Хочу собрать коллекцию алгоритмов сортировки списков (двухсвязных и односвязных), но в инете ничего нет. Помогите кто может.

```
program main;
const a: array[1..8] of Integer = (153, 967, 8, 0, 9, 22, 35, 1);
type List=^node;
     node=record
        data: Integer;
        next: list
        end;
var lst: List;

procedure InputSeq(var head: List);
var p,q: List;
begin
    while not EoLn do begin
        new(p);
        read(p^.data);
        if head=nil then
            head:=p
        else q^.next:=p;
        q:=p;
    end;
    p^.next:=nil;
end;

procedure CreateBinFile();
var f:file of Integer;
    i: Integer;
begin
    assign (f,'sequence.dat');
    rewrite (f);
    i:=1;
    while i<=8 do begin
        write (f,a[i]);
        i:=i+1;
    end;
    close (f);
end;

procedure OutputSeq(head: List);
var p: List;
begin
    p:=head;
    while p<>nil do begin
        write(p^.data, ' ');
        p:=p^.next;
    end;
end;

function FirstDigit(n: Integer): Integer;
var first: Integer;
begin
    while n<>0 do begin
        first:=n mod 10;
        n:=n div 10;
    end;
    FirstDigit:=first;
end;

procedure swap(p, q: List);
var temp: List;
begin
    temp:=p;
    p:=q;
    p^.next:=q^.next;
    q:=temp;
    q^.next:=p;
end;

procedure InsertDownSort(head: List);
var p, q, key: List;
begin
    p:=head^.next;
    while p <> nil do begin
        key:=p;
        while (p <> nil) and (p^.data > key^.data) do
            p^.next:=p;
        p^.next:=key;
    end;
end;

procedure BubbleDownSort(var head: List);
var p, q, key: List; 
    temp: Integer;
begin
    p:=head;
    while p<>nil do begin
        q:=p;
        key:=q;
        while q<>nil do begin
            if FirstDigit(key^.data) <= FirstDigit(q^.data) then 
                key:=q;
            q:=q^.next
        end;
        temp:=p^.data; 
        p^.data:=key^.data; 
        key^.data:=temp;
        p:=p^.next
    end
end;

begin
    if not (FileExists('sequence.dat')) then
        CreateBinFile();
    InputSeq(lst);
    InsertDownSort(lst);
    OutputSeq(lst);
end.
```

Comment: Наверно так и есть. Я просто смотрел на описание алгоритма на вики и пытался писать. В случае с массивами всегда получалось написать правильно, но со списками не сработало.

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаток паскаля, но что-то мне подсказывает, что тело этого цикла

```
    key:=p;
    while (p <> nil) and (p^.data > key^.data) do
        p^.next:=p;
```

ни разу не выполнится.

Указатели `p^` и `кеу^` в условии вначале равны, соответственно поля `data` тоже равны, а в условии выполнения цикла операция сравнения - `>`.

Кстати, если список пустой, то IMHO программа просто упадет.